Mailjet: display content if variable value is a specific string
I'm passing some variables to a Mailjet template via Zapier. Sometimes the variables will contain no data, and sometimes they will contain certain strings. I'd like to display specific html when certain strings are present, and display no html when it's empty.
{% if var:City = "New York City" %}
   <div>All the New York City Content</div>
{% endif %}

No matter what I've tried, Mailjet just sends back an error with "Unknown identifier" if the variable is blank. What am I missing?
· · · · · ·
Also, is there a way to ask Mailjet to look for just a specific string that could be part of the value? For example:
{% if var:City contains "New York" %}
   <div>All the New York City Content</div>
{% endif %}

